# Simple JS with deffining functions

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, semantics

I'm creating a simple questionare using prompts for a website, but i am having issues.

I am recieving two errors with this script, firstly "question is not deffined" ,

secondly "missing ) after argument list" on the line with my first prompt any ideas?

```
<script>
var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var b = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var c = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

var wrong = 0;

function question()
{   
    for(x=1; x>10; x++)
    {
        prompt("Does" b"+"c " = ");
        if(prompt.input == b + c)
        {
            question();
        }else{
            wrong++;
        }

        if(x==10)
        {
            alert("well you were wrong " + wrong" times");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be skipping concatenation operators in several places

Comment: Start at [jshint.com](http://jshint.com/). You can untick all of the warnings for now, you'll have plenty of feedback with just the errors.

Comment: Also, `prompt.input`? How did you arrive at this code? Just your best guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing all `+` in the argument to

```
prompt("Does" b"+"c " = ");
```

You have to use `+` to concatenate strings:

```
prompt("Does " + b + "+" + c + " = ");
```

The same `+` is missing in:

```
alert("well you were wrong " + wrong" times");
```

Use:

```
alert("well you were wrong " + wrong + " times");
```

---

Also, you are calling `question` from within itself. This doesn't cause a syntax error, but it's hardly desired in your case.

---

Also, `prompt.input` doesn't work. It's always undefined. Use the return value of the prompt call:

```
var response = prompt( ... );
if(response == b+c){
  ...
```

---

Also, you are only initialising your random variables once. Perhaps you want a new pair within each loop (unless the recursion was meant for that). Thanks @Asad for noting.

Comment: Good call, i've missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be skipping concatenation operators in several places. A correct version would look like this:

```
prompt("Does " + b + "+" + c + " = ");
```

Once again, here:

```
alert("well you were wrong " + wrong + " times");
```

Additionally:

1. Your random numbers need to be randomized again at the beginning of
   the loop
2. `question` does not need recursion (you are already using a loop)
3. The alert for how many times the user was wrong needs to happen outside the loop

Here is a corrected version:

```
var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var b = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
var c = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

var wrong = 0;

function question()
{   
    for(x=1; x>10; x++)
    {
        b = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        c = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
        prompt("Does " + b + "+" + c + " = ");
        if(prompt.input != b + c)
            wrong++;        
    }

    alert("well you were wrong " + wrong + " times");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var f1 = alert("well you were wrong " + wrong + " times");
```

`alert` doesn't`return a value.

Missing string concatenation:

```
"Does" b"+"c " = "
"Does"+ b + "+" + c + " = "
```

(I'd suggest checking all your strings)

Also, with your recursion with a loop in it, you're generating a infinite loop:
(Slightly simplified)

```
function question(){

    for(x=1; x>10; x++){
        question();
    }
}
```

You're calling `question();` 10 times, each time you call `question();`.

Comment: It is still valid feedback for other users that might read this.
Not a reason to downvote.

Comment: I'm trying to cause a loop 10 times

Comment: @Asad already pretty much wrote how that should be done. I could write my own, but it'd be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

`question is not defined` means that your function `question` is being called before it actually was read by browser.

Make sure that main JS code is being executed only after window.ready event was triggered.

```
window.onready = function(){
    //Here your starting code goes
}
```

Comment: Where's nothing to wait for. The question is called from within itself, so it's already defined when it's called.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, and what calls it for first time?

Comment: That is good to know. Still, you don't need to wait for the page load.

Comment: @JanDvorak This not waiting for page loading is successfully crashing IE before 9 if you try to change DOM using jQuery before it has been built completely

Comment: @JanDvorak It is just good practice to wait for resources to load. window.load only means that all text files were received and pre-processed. All images are still being loaded with JS code working at the same time. In that case it is much easier to predict what can happen.

Comment: window.load waits for the images

Comment: Oops, my mistake. It should be window.ready, not window.load.

Comment: That's a jQuery event. Still, jQuery is a great library and should be used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are errors in concatenation of strings. Should be like

```
prompt("Does" +b+c+" = ");
alert("well you were wrong " + wrong+" times");
```

Secondly you are recurrently using function `question();` without upgration of value which creates a loop

Comment: I am trying to cause a loop 10 times, but each time will be different because of the random numbers.